# Android with eclipse

Tags: android

I've started learning coding for the android, I know the basics of programming in general and thought that android would be fun, Which it has so far.

Now in my exercises in the book I have, It says to add more text to the application. The application is nothing at the moment but 1 string, And I have to add another string.

Now when I have added the string to the strings.xml file and then on the main.xml I type:

android:text="@string/AppName" />

AppName is the new string I made which in the strings.xml it looks like this:

This App is called Droid1

The weird thing is when I type in the main xml to referr to the string, It doesnt even get colour coded when I type the android:text part. The whole line stays as the black text colour. Im sure im not missing anything as the string is all colour coded and so is the last string that I referred to while following the examples in the book which is:

android:text="@string/hello" />

And this is what is confusing me. So please point out the obvious or not so obvious thing that I have done wrong. Any help at all will be appreciated

Comment: If you read it you would realise that I must be doing something wrong with strings, I cant get them to show on AVD when trying to do the exercise in a book I have, But when I followed the book Yesterday I got strings to work without any dramas. Its not even getting the colour codes in eclipse when I try to add a string in main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses the [XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) to define interfaces and such. The line

```
android:text="@string/AppName" />
```

is not valid XML, and the black syntax is Eclipse's way of showing this. This is probably because you have forgotten to put some lines above it. What you want to have is something like this:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/AppName" />
```

This tells Android that you would like to put a `TextView` (or, a text label or whatever) with your string in it. Also note that the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes here are **always required**: without them, you will get an error and you can't build your application.

If you are not already familiar XML, I would highly recommend taking a look at an XML tutorial (for instance at [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/) or [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/)) and learn the basics of XML, since understanding the XML language simplifies Android programming a lot.

Comment: Thanks dude, I didnt realise you had to add the android:layout to every string, Thats where I screwed up, As In my first string I have them, then for the second string I tried just adding the android:text directly under the last android:text string. Thus in me creating a new TextView, This has worked great. Thank you very much,  And I will definetly have to read up on xml. Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

If you want your text to have color, you can set `android:textColor="######"` in your xml either textview or whatever you used to display the string. `######` is your color code.

Comment: No thats not what I mean, Im adding the string but its not showing up in an AVD where as yesterday when I followed the book, It worked fine.